# How do I perform async operations in a aiohttp request handler after sending the response?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to perform async operations in a aiohttp request handler after sending the response. As [per docs](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-perform-operations-in-a-request-handler-after-sending-the-response) I should write

```py
async def ping_handler(request):
    """Send PONG and increase DB counter."""

    # explicitly send the response
    resp = web.json_response({'message': 'PONG'})
    await resp.prepare(request)
    await resp.write_eof()

    # job after sending resp
    time.sleep(1)

    return resp
```

This recipe works great for non-async functions. But when I use `asyncio.sleep`, it failes:

```py
async def ping_handler(request):
    """Send PONG and increase DB counter."""

    # explicitly send the response
    resp = web.json_response({'message': 'PONG'})
    await resp.prepare(request)
    await resp.write_eof()

    # job after sending resp
    print('Enter job')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Exit job')

    return resp
```

I see `Enter job`, but no `Exit job`.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this code runs? `await` should run only under `async def` AFAIK

Comment: @F.Leone fix my question. First piece of code runs without errors.